# Remove Bullets from @Html.ValidationSummary() in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I remove remove bullets from `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in MVC4. Any suggestions?

```html
<span class="help-block" style="list-style-type: none;"> 
    @Html.ValidationSummary() 
</span>
```

Comment: I have done like this :    <span class="help-block" style="list-style-type: none;">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()
                </span>   but its not working.

Answer (score 19):

Given that your comment describes your code like this:

```html
<span class="help-block">
    @Html.ValidationSummary() 
</span>
```

You can set the CSS property `list-style-type` to `none` on the `ul` element which the `ValidationSummary` generates. Try this:

```css
.help-block ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
.validation-summary-errors ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:-40px
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But instead of `margin-left: -40px`, just simply use `padding-left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Html.ValidationSummary() at the top of the page!

Because it generates `<ul>,<li>` tags automatically.

Im my case I have an input field named "WebSite" and I am getting error like this(look at html codes by pressing F12 on browser):

```
<ul>
       <li>The Website field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp URL.</li>
<ul/>
```

Solution=> Remove @Html.ValidationSummary() from cshtml and put erros after input element. For my case:

```
<input type="text" name="Website" value="@Model.Website" />
```

(errorfield here)=>  `<span asp-validation-for="Website" style="color:red"></span>`

Regards